# Grapher - What is wrong with my Rbx.Lua Script?

Tags: graph, lua, equations, roblox, parametric-equations

I have a script for the Roblox version of Lua. Roblox's syntax checking system says that there is nothing wrong with my script. The script is supposed to create a graph of a circle using 'Parts' or 'Bricks'. Below is the wiki page I got the graph function from.

I think bounds.from is the current position of the brick; bounds.to is the next calculated position of the next brick; bounds.step is the counter for what step is being taken - meaning you can change the resolution of the graph (Like 1,000 points or 10,000 points)

[Wiki page for graph function. The 'Making a Grapher' is what I used.](http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=Parametric_equations)

```
local p = Instance.new("Part")
p.Anchored      = true
p.BottomSurface = "Smooth"
p.TopSurface    = "Smooth"
p.BrickColor    = BrickColor.Black()
p.FormFactor    = "Custom"
p.Size          = Vector3.new(1, 1, 1)

function graph(bounds, f)
    bounds.step = bounds.step or (bounds.max - bounds.min) / bounds.n
    for t = bounds.from, bounds.to, bounds.step do
        local xyz = f(t)
        local p = p.clone()
        p.CFrame = CFrame.new(xyz)
        p.Parent = game.Workspace
    end
end

graph({from = 0, to = math.pi * 12, n = 1000}, function(t)
    return Vector3.new(
        5 * math.cos(t),
        5 * math.sin(t),
        0
    )
end)
```

PS: I am in Algebra 1 so I don't know sines, cosines, and tangents nor parametric equations.

Comment: Well, what _is_ wrong with it? What do you expect to happen? What happens instead?

Comment: The script is supposed to graph a circle using 3D bricks in the Roblox game engine. Instead nothing happens.

Comment: Hey, could you give us a screenshot of what it's drawing? I'm at work and don't have access to studio - though I may be able to help if you post a picture.

Comment: It doesn't draw anything. No errors are reported in the Output console and no bricks are created within the workspace. I click play and the baseplate stays a baseplate.

Comment: I uninstalled and reinstalled Roblox studio. This fixed part of the problem. I am now getting an error as shown below. I'm not sure what to do. `12:18:07.320 - Workspace.Script:10: attempt to index field 'max' (a nil value)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While looking over the code initially, I noticed quite a few syntax errors, so I looked at the code on the Roblox Wiki, and was surprised to see that the code you've provided matches theirs.

*Setting aside the fact that the Roblox Wiki is maintaining broken code, let's take a look at why your code isn't working, and what you can do to fix it.*

I'll start with the problem you're having, which originates from the statement `bounds.step = bounds.step or (bounds.max - bounds.min) / bounds.n`
(Because of how Lua works, the interpretor reads this as `(bounds[max] - bounds[min]) / bounds.n`, as `table.value` is syntactic sugar for `table[value]`, and we never defined `bounds.max` or `bounds.min`, which is why you're getting the error.)

The proper way to evaluate that expression is to call `math.max()` and `math.min()` with explicit arguments, like so: `(math.max(bounds.from, bounds.to) - math.min(bounds.from, bounds.to)) / bounds.n`, as neither is coded to be used as a method, and can only take integers/floats as parameters anyway; tables are not permissible, and **will** return an error.

A second error I noticed, and one that would have shown up after fixing the above issue, was that for cloning the template part (defined as `local p` in the Global scope), the original code's writer used `p.clone()`, which actually returns this error: `01:49:37.933 - Expected ':' not '.' calling member function clone`

The returned response for this error is pretty self-descriptive, but I'll say it anyways: in order to fix this error, simply replace `local p = p.clone()` with `local p = p:clone()` inside the graph function.

In case that explanation was too confusing, or you just didn't feel like reading it, I've provided the fixed code (in-full) down below.

Happy coding.

---

TL;DR, or Fixed code:

```
local p = Instance.new("Part")
p.Anchored      = true
p.BottomSurface = "Smooth"
p.TopSurface    = "Smooth"
p.BrickColor    = BrickColor.Black()
p.FormFactor    = "Custom"
p.Size          = Vector3.new(1, 1, 1)

function graph(bounds, f)
    bounds.step = bounds.step or (math.max(bounds.from, bounds.to) - math.min(bounds.from, bounds.to)) / bounds.n
    for t = bounds.from, bounds.to, bounds.step do
        local xyz = f(t)
        local p = p:clone()
        p.CFrame = CFrame.new(xyz)
        p.Parent = game.Workspace
    end
end

graph({from = 0, to = math.pi * 12, n = 1000}, function(t)
    return Vector3.new(
        5 * math.cos(t),
        5 * math.sin(t),
        0
    )
end)
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! I read your entire post and understood the problem. I am making a program that graphs trade currency rates using a separate python-based web scraper and HttpService. I will try to convert this script to use GUIs instead so it is easier. It will be part of Robux Academy - a series of 'Get Rich' pay-to-access games if you want to see this in action in a few months.

Comment: I want to make each point more visible on the graph because 13.742 as an X position (In Workspace, not StarterGUI) is not very far from 13.746. I think subtracting the whole number (In this case, 13) from the number and then multiplying it by 10 or more would make it more visible. I am not sure how to do this though.

Comment: @GShocked 

If you need additional help, try posting in the following thread on the ROBLOX forums: [Game Design](http://www.roblox.com/Forum/ShowForum.aspx?ForumID=40). There are many people (including myself) willing to provide help to those who ask.